# How to send php mail attachment with original filename

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments, pear

I send email with attachment, everything is working, but I get email with attachment temporary name. What is wrong with this code ?

```
foreach ($_FILES["file"]["name"] as $k => $v) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$k];
        $name = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][$k]);
        $mail->AddAttachment($tmp_name,$name);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O1mg.png)

Comment: Don't see anything wrong in code. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want to get email with attachment which have original filename. But in this case I'm getting attachment with temp_name and don't understand why. In picture you can see that attachment name is phptFMw0J instead of original name

Comment: What name you are getting when you echo `$name` ?

Comment: original name: image.png. Everything is good with $name

Answer (score 1):

try doing this works for me

```
if (array_key_exists('filename', $_FILES))
            {
                 foreach ($_FILES["filename"]["name"] as $k => $v) 
                 {
                    $mail->addAttachment( $_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"][$k], 
                    $_FILES["filename"]["name"][$k] );
                 }                
            }
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone OP ??

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Oh okay! Why though?

Comment: op's using `$_FILES["file"]` other than that the code is the same.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That was intentional, op will put his filename there.

Comment: Don't use what's in `$_FILES` directly – it's unsafe. Read [the PHP docs on handling file uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).